# How to create a variable in Python to store a number with 500 digits after decimal?

Tags: python

I need to find 500 digits after decimal of e. The output variable limits the number of digits to 16. How do you go forth with it?

Comment: By the way, it's not any kind of "output variable" (which doesn't really exist) that's limiting the precision, it's the `float` type that can't store more digits because it has only 52 bits available to store the fraction (and 11 for the exponent, one for the sign).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 501
>>> a = decimal.Decimal("2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166427427466391932003059921817413596629043572900334295260595630738132328627943490763233829880753195251019011573834187930702154089149934884167509244761460668082264800168477411853742345442437107539077744992069551702761838606261331384583000752044933826560297606737113200709328709127443747047230696977209310141692836819025515108657463772111252389784425056953696770785449969967946864454905987931636889230098793127")
>>> print a
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166427427466391932003059921817413596629043572900334295260595630738132328627943490763233829880753195251019011573834187930702154089149934884167509244761460668082264800168477411853742345442437107539077744992069551702761838606261331384583000752044933826560297606737113200709328709127443747047230696977209310141692836819025515108657463772111252389784425056953696770785449969967946864454905987931636889230098793127
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I wanted to know hpw do you find this 500 digited number? As in, I know the iterative way to generate digits of e but how do I print all the 500 digits?

Comment: Ah, your title said 100. Well, just increase the precision to 501. Then just `print` the `Decimal` and it will be output with all 501 digits.

Comment: If you do not want to calculate e yourself, you could get it by `decimal.Decimal(1).exp()` with whatever precision you like.